# Finding Minimum Spanning tree using Prim Algorithms and display edges of Minimum spanning tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I use Prism Algorithm to find the Minimum Spanning tree and also I am using Java Priority Queue(Min-heap) as a way to sort the nodes.

I am assigning each node. key to Affinity except for the start node(a) which in this case has zero key value.

here's what I have got so far, but I'm not getting desired output.

```
// Priority Queue Implementation
    Comparator<Node> cm = new KeyComparator();
    public ArrayList<Edge> MST_PRIM() {
    PriorityQueue<Node> Q = new PriorityQueue<Node>(graph.getNodeList().size(),cm); // from java.util

        ArrayList<Edge> MST = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        // Initialize
        for (Node n1 : graph.getNodeList()) {

            n1.setKey(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            n1.setPreviousNode(null);

        } // end of the loop

        // set key of start node to zero
        graph.startingNode().setKey(0);
        

        // add all vertices into Queue
        for (Node n : graph.getNodeList()) {
            Q.add(n);
        }

        // while Q is not empty
        while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
            Node n3 = Q.poll();// extract-minHeap
// add the edge into the  MSTlist
            if (n3.getPreviousNode() != null) {
                Edge e = n3.findEdge(n3.getPreviousNode());
                MST.add(e);

            }


            for (Edge e : n3.getOutgoingEdges()) {
                // let me sort outgoing edges

                Node v = e.getHead();

                if (Q.contains(v) && e.getDistance() < v.getKey()) {
                    v.setPreviousNode(e.getTail());
                    v.setKey(e.getDistance());

                } // end of if
            } // end of for loop
            

        }

        return MST;
```

here is KeyComparator class

```java
import java.util.Comparator;

public class KeyComparator  implements Comparator<Node>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Node n, Node n1) {
        if(n.getKey() < n1.getKey())
            return -1;
        else if (n.getKey() > n1.getKey())
            return 1;
        
        else return n.getName().compareTo(n1.getName());
    }

}
```

the Node Class

```
import java.util.*;

// A node of a graph for the Spring 2018 ICS 340 program

public class Node  {

    private String name;
    private String value; // The value of the Node which was stored in the value column
    private String abbrev; // The abbreviation for the Node
    private ArrayList<Edge> outgoingEdges;
    private ArrayList<Edge> incomingEdges;
    // for Delivery B
    private String color;
    private Node previous;
    public int d; // discovery time
    public int f; // final time
    
    // for Delivery C
    public Integer key;
    
    
    
    
    

    public Integer getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Integer key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Node(String abbreviation) {
        abbrev = abbreviation;
        value = null;
        name = null;
        outgoingEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        incomingEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        
        
    }
    
    // add to adjacent nodes
    
//  public void addToAdj( Node n) {
//      
//          
//      } // end of adjacent nodes
//      
    //public ArrayList<Node> getAdjacentNodes() {
        //return adjacentNodes;
        
    //}
        
        
        
    //}

    public String getAbbrev() {
        return abbrev;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> getOutgoingEdges() {
        return outgoingEdges;
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> getIncomingEdges() {
        return incomingEdges;
    }

    public void setAbbrev(String abbreviation) {
        abbrev = abbreviation;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void addOutgoingEdge(Edge e) {
        outgoingEdges.add(e);
    }

    public void addIncomingEdge(Edge e) {
        incomingEdges.add(e);
    }
     // all about color
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color =color;
    }
    
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    
    // all about previous Node
    public void setPreviousNode (Node n) {
        this.previous = n;
    }
    
    public Node getPreviousNode () {
        return previous;
    }
    

    // tostring to format
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + abbrev + " has outDegree " + outgoingEdges.size() + " and Indegree " + incomingEdges.size()
                + " degree of node is " + (outgoingEdges.size() + incomingEdges.size());
    }

// to format Indegree
    public String formatIn() {
        return "Node " + abbrev + " has indegree " + incomingEdges.size();

    }

    // to format outDegree
    public String formatOut() {
        return "Node " + abbrev + " has outdegree " + outgoingEdges.size();

    }
    
    // to format Edges of MSP
        public String formatMSP() {
            return  abbrev;
        }
    
    

    
    //  find edge method
    public Edge findEdge(Node n) {
        // n is parent
        for(Edge e : incomingEdges) {
            if(e.getTail().equals(n)) {
                return e;
            }
            
            
            
        }// end for loop
        
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (key == null) {
            if (other.key != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!key.equals(key.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    

}
```

to see the whole code click  here [enter link description here](https://github.com/roycas99/Data-stucture-and-algo/tree/master/Data-Sttructure-and-Algorithms-master)

this is the graph I am working on it
[image]

desire output is lool like this:

[image]

here is what I getting:

[image]

Comment: start node of this graph is Node A.

Comment: I don't see any difference in your desired output and the screen showing what you get in your output.

Comment: the order of the edges is not the same. for example, after the C-B edge, it is supposed to be the I-C edge that comes next not the D-C edge in my case. thanks

Comment: Why does the order matter? You can represent a tree in any order of the edges.

Comment: because this algorithm is greedy which means we always chose the optical solution.  in this case, if where at the C node we can go to the I, D, and F nodes but we have chosen the node with the shortest Path which is I ( because it has 2 costs). I hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue  (the MSP-edges order)  by removing the node from Priority Queue before updating the key and adding back after updating its key

```
if (Q.contains(v) && e.getDistance() < v.getKey()) {
                    Q.remove(v); // remove the node from Queue before update their key
                    v.setPreviousNode(e.getTail());
                    v.setKey(e.getDistance());
                    Q.add(v); // add the node back to the Queue after update their key
```

I did some modification to  Equal boolean method in Node class.

```
//use name field  for equality because each node has unique name. do not use key field.
// this is important for KeyComparator class
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```